# python flask multiprocessing program sometimes hangs forever

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, flask, multiprocessing

I have a python program that processes data with `mutliprocessing` module.

This program runs inside a flask server.

The following block of code sometimes stucks forever.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
multiprocessing.log_to_stderr().setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

...

def linear_regression():
    ...

print("before pool")
traceback.print_stack()
with Pool() as p:
    param = [(x, data[i + 1 - n:i + 1]) for i in indices_dict.get(False, [])]
    print(f"param: {param}")
    result = p.starmap(linear_regression, param)
    print(f"result: {result}")
    result = [t[0] for t in result]
    print(f"result2: {result}")
print("after pool")
```

Here's the log when it stops running:

```
before pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975849271296
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975843381248
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975840456704
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-89] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-90] child process calling self.run()
min_square_get_slopes param: [(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), ...]
min_square_get_slopes result: [(-0.1, 0.2), (-0.3, -0.4)]
min_square_get_slopes result2: [1, 2, 3, ...]
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <bound method Pool._terminate_pool of <class 'multiprocessing.pool.Pool'>> with args (<_queue.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4ea7b0ab80>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e4600edf0>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e63977940>, [<ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-89' pid=368 parent=31 started daemon>, <ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-90' pid=369 parent=31 started daemon>], <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e461129d0>, <Thread(Thread-140, started daemon 139975173588736)>, <Thread(Thread-141, started daemon 139975165196032)>, <Thread(Thread-142, started daemon 139975156803328)>, {}) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] finalizing pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] worker handler exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ensuring that outqueue is not full
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler exiting: len(cache)=0, thread._state=RUN
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-89] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-89] worker exiting after 4 tasks
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-90] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-89] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-90] worker exiting after 4 tasks
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-89] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-90] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-90] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-89] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-89] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-90] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-90] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] helping task handler/workers to finish
[DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining worker handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] terminating workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining task handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining pool workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] cleaning up worker 368
<value of the final result>
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function close_fds at 0x7f4e98184af0> with args (24, 27) and kwargs {}
```

As you can see from the log above, `after pool` never got printed.

And here's log when it runs correctly.

```
before pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975849271296
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975843381248
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975840456704
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-87] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-88] child process calling self.run()
min_square_get_slopes param: [(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), ...]
min_square_get_slopes result: []
min_square_get_slopes result2: []
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <bound method Pool._terminate_pool of <class 'multiprocessing.pool.Pool'>> with args (<_queue.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e6382dc20>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e46252460>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e8853cb80>, [<ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-87' pid=363 parent=31 started daemon>, <ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-88' pid=364 parent=31 started daemon>], <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x7f4e4600e580>, <Thread(Thread-137, started daemon 139975156803328)>, <Thread(Thread-138, started daemon 139975173588736)>, <Thread(Thread-139, started daemon 139975165196032)>, {}) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] finalizing pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] helping task handler/workers to finish
[DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
[DEBUG/MainProcess] worker handler exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to workers
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-87] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-87] worker exiting after 4 tasks
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-87] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-87] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-87] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-87] process exiting with exitcode 0
<value of the final result>
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ensuring that outqueue is not full
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler exiting: len(cache)=0, thread._state=RUN
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler exiting
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-88] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-88] worker exiting after 4 tasks
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-88] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-88] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-88] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-88] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining worker handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] terminating workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining task handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining pool workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] cleaning up worker 363
[DEBUG/MainProcess] cleaning up worker 364
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function close_fds at 0x7f4e98184af0> with args (25, 29) and kwargs {}
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function close_fds at 0x7f4e98184af0> with args (24, 27) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975854231552
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975854227456
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 139975853420544
<value of the final result>
after pool
```

Does anyone have clues about why it sometimes hang?

Is this a deadlock?

This problem might have something to do with flask server; because when I extract this block of code to a simple python script, it never hangs.

Here are the information about my versions:

- python version: `3.8.7`
- flask version: `1.1.4`

The flask server runs inside a docker container. The container uses `python:3.8.7` docker image to setup the server.

This docker image's OS versioin is `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`.

Here's my `app.py`

```
# Third-party Libraries
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask import flash
from flask_restful import Api
...

# Self Libraries
from api.resources.report import ReportResource


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'the_secret'
        
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
    login_manager.login_view = 'login'
    users = {
        'userA': {
            'password': 'passA'
        },
        'userB': {
            'password': 'passB'
        },
    }

    ...

    @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template("login.html")
        
        userName = request.form['user_id']
        if (userName in users) and (request.form['password'] == users[userName]['password']):
            user = User()
            user.id = userName
            login_user(user)
            return redirect('/homepage')

        return render_template('login.html')

    @app.route('/logout')
    def logout():
        userName = current_user.get_id()
        logout_user()
        return render_template('login.html')

    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    api = Api(app)
    api.add_resource(ReportResource, '/report/generate/the-report')

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

`app.py` is located under `api/` folder.

The program is started up by running `python3 -m api.app` in the root folder.

Here's the root folder structure:

```
.
│
├── api
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── app.py
    ├── resources
    │   └── report.py
```

The multi-process API is triggered by sending a POST request to `/report/generate/the-report`.

Here's the stack trace I get when running `traceback.print_stack()`.

This line of code runs after `print("before pool")`.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 72, in task
    data=self.main(data),
  File "/root/my-program/etl/extracts/report_extract.py", line 364, in main
    calibration_point_info_list = SomeMysteryFunction().main(formula_compose)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/extracts/report_extract.py", line 545, in main
    sn_ab_objs, cc_objs, cal_objs = self.prepare_data(data_input)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/extracts/report_extract.py", line 472, in prepare_data
    o.data for o in RawData2CC(
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 106, in run
    results = self.__class__.get_pool(nodes).uimap(self.task, input_iterable)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 44, in get_pool
    return etl_type.PUBLIC_PROCESS_POOLS.setdefault(nodes, ProcessPool(nodes=nodes))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 109, in __init__
    self._serve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 121, in _serve
    _pool = Pool(nodes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/popen_fork.py", line 75, in _launch
    code = process_obj._bootstrap(parent_sentinel=child_r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 72, in task
    data=self.main(data),
  File "/root/my-program/etl/transforms/report_transform.py", line 721, in main
    smooth_metrics = SmoothMetrics(cgm)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 398, in __init__
    SmoothMetrics.__init__(self, Line(self.target_data), Line(self.baseline_data), Line(self.shape_line))
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 247, in __init__
    else Line.get_sharp_score_array(self.diff_array)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 304, in get_sharp_score_array
    slope_array = min_square_func(data_array, slope_length + 1)
  File "/root/my-program/data_process.py", line 109, in min_square_func
    traceback.print_stack()
```

If I press Ctrl+C when the program hangs, I get the following stack trace:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] cleaning up worker 336
[DEBUG/MainProcess] cleaning up worker 337

^C[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-68] process shutting down
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-46] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-68] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-46] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-46] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-68] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-46] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-68] process exiting with exitcode 0
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 72, in task
    data=self.main(data),
  File "/root/my-program/etl/transforms/daily_report_transform.py", line 721, in main
    smooth_metrics = SenSmoothMetrics(cgm)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 398, in __init__
    SmoothMetrics.__init__(self, Line(self.target_data), Line(self.baseline_data), Line(self.shape_line))
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 247, in __init__
    else Line.get_sharp_score_array(self.diff_array)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 304, in get_sharp_score_array
    slope_array = min_square_get_slopes(data_array, slope_length + 1)
  File "/root/my-program/data_process.py", line 113, in min_square_get_slopes
    result = [t[0] for t in result]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 736, in __exit__
    self.terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 654, in terminate
    self._terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 729, in _terminate_pool
    p.join()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "/root/my-program/etl/base.py", line 72, in task
    data=self.main(data),
  File "/root/my-program/etl/transforms/daily_report_transform.py", line 721, in main
    smooth_metrics = SenSmoothMetrics(cgm)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 398, in __init__
    SmoothMetrics.__init__(self, Line(self.target_data), Line(self.baseline_data), Line(self.shape_line))
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 247, in __init__
    else Line.get_sharp_score_array(self.diff_array)
  File "/root/my-program/analysis/Metrics.py", line 304, in get_sharp_score_array
    slope_array = min_square_get_slopes(data_array, slope_length + 1)
  File "/root/my-program/data_process.py", line 113, in min_square_get_slopes
    result = [t[0] for t in result]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 736, in __exit__
    self.terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 654, in terminate
    self._terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 729, in _terminate_pool
    p.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 47, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer no longer registered
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function close_fds at 0x7fea2a2e1af0> with args (24, 27) and kwargs {}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 47, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer no longer registered
[Level 5/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function close_fds at 0x7fea2a2e1af0> with args (22, 25) and kwargs {}
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

Comment: this smells to me like recursively creating child processes via code not protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":` any code that could ever lead to a child process being launched should not be reachable by import. when using flask with multiprocessing put the `app = Flask(app_path)` and all `@app.route` def's inside `if __name__ ...`

Comment: or not necessarily creating child processes, but a child server in the child process that is preventing the `atexit` functions from all finishing as expected

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your seggestion. I'm trying adding `app = Flask(app_path)` and `@app.route` inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` now. I'll tell you if it works later.

Comment: The problem still exists after moving `app = Flask(app_path)` and `@app.route` inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`.     :-(

Comment: well... it's good practice anyway. I've answered flask multiprocessing questions where it was the problem. I'm looking closely at that last log line now regarding releasing file handles..

Comment: Can you please give the OS, python version, flask version, and how you launch the server? some additional code to how `Pool` gets called may help as well (part of an `@route`?). also anything like if you set a particular start method, or use a non-standard context. On possibility is fork is not playing nice with a thread / lock created by flask

Comment: @Aaron, sure, I've pasted those information in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239468/discussion-between-aaron-and-brian).

Comment: I do not see in your Flask code where you call `multiprocessing`, can you share it?

Comment: The flask code calling my multiprocessing.Pool() is placed deep inside other functions, I'm still trying to print its stacktrace.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev, I just paste the stack trace before `multiprocessing.Pool()` is called.

Comment: @Brian it is great but where do you call it in your app code? Probably you get several requests and each of them create new child processes and eventually you have too many processes to handle?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev, I'm not quite sure about what you mean. Do you mean all the codes from `ReportResource` class's `post()` method to `with Pool() as p:`?

Comment: If yes, it contains a lot of methods and classes. I'm still thinking about how to represent it in the question without revealing my company's sensitive data.

Comment: @Brian yes, I need to see how and where you start child processes. You can substitute your sensitive code with something like `10**100000000....` it will simulate heavy CPU-bound task. And please simplify all example, the problem is not related to Flask auth ops.